# Avoiding Invalid Path format error in D3 updates

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having an issue with d3 tree layout when adding nodes dynamically.

Depending on the node type, I add a path symbol to the node, however on update I get an error saying "invalid path format".

Both the Enter and update use the same code:

```
nodeUpdate.select("path")
                .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d)
                {
                    return self.TypeToShape(d.Type);
                })
                .size(150))
                .attr("transform", function(d) 
                { 
                    var transform="translate(" + 2 + "," + -1 + ")"
                    if (d.Type==="e")
                    {
                        transform = transform+" rotate(30)"; 
                    }
                    return transform;
                })
                .style("fill", function(d){
                    return self.TypeToColour(d.Type);
                });
```

Enter does not seem to cause the issue, only update.

I'm new to D3, so I'm wondering if I have missed something conceptually about how d3 works that may cause this.

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z15825qu/

Comment: What should we do in the fiddle to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Add child nodes & add nodes to the children. about 12 errors will appear in browser debug window for each grandchild. IE11.

Comment: And how do I add a node?

Comment: Click on the node, click 'add child' in the pop-up, click ok

Comment: You're transitioning the SVG symbols, which generates the invalid paths. If you don't do that and simply update them, it works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/z15825qu/4/

Comment: Thanks Lars, that's perfect can you add this as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're transitioning the SVG symbols, which generates invalid `path`s. To fix, simply don't transition them:

```
node.select("path")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.symbol().type(function(d) {
        return self.TypeToShape(d.Type);
    })
```

Complete example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z15825qu/4/).